# Create static instance for class

Tags: c++

so I'm trying to create static instance of class, so I can access it from anywhere.

`RenderWindow.hpp`

> 1. way

```
class RenderWindow{
 // ... code
 
  static RenderWindow* INSTANCE;
}

RenderWindow* window("Jump Game", 600, 700, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
RenderWindow::INSTANCE = &window;
```

> 2. way

```
static RenderWindow* RENDER_WINDOW = NULL;
static RenderWindow* GetRenderWindow()
{
    if (RENDER_WINDOW == NULL)
    {
        RenderWindow window("Jump Game", 600, 700, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
        RENDER_WINDOW = &window;
    }

    return RENDER_WINDOW;
}
```

I tried this but with none of them works..

Comment: Please include the error you're getting.

Comment: This is generally called a "singleton" here is a [reference on how to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern)

Comment: In C++ use `nullptr` in preference to C's typeless `NULL`.

Comment: Re: "so I can access it from anywhere" -- so you want it to be **global** (not static).